# Android app background resolution

Tags: android, background

I have 2 devices and my background work correctely on only one device. How can i fill all drawable file with correct background resolution ? Did he exist an soft for transform my background for all resolution?

Comment: see this: it provides a tool http://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/18/create-android-hdpi-mdpi-and-ldpi-images-out-of-a-single-xhdpi-png-image/

Comment: This is what i want but this tool wasn't update since 5 years and doesn't support xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. Thank you for this answer ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the best dimensions for the app to run in all devices. For understanding multiple supporting screens you have to read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

xxxhdpi: 1280x1920 px
xxhdpi: 960x1600 px
xhdpi: 640x960 px
hdpi: 480x800 px
mdpi: 320x480 px
ldpi: 240x320 px

Comment: I need to resize image myself ? Did he exist a soft for do that ?

Comment: yes you have to resize your image and put it in different folders with same name. folder structure will be as above XXXHDPI,XXHDPI,HDPI,MDPI,LDPI

Answer (score 0):

You can use .SVG image file to support all resolutions.

Add svg file in drawables using Vector assests.

Comment: Yes i know but i haven't my backgournd image in .SVG (it's .PNG). But i think .SVG files are use for icon.

Comment: Ok, so you have to resize your images as per android developer guide for screen supports.